# Using graph properties as an input in Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I have almost 1000 of pandas DataFrame, which I converted into graphs. Now I can access edges and nodes of those graphs. For one DataFrame it looks like following:

```
nx.edges(FG)

Out[59]: EdgeView([('Dy0O7', 'Dy1O6'), ('Dy0O7', 'Dy2O6'), ('Dy0O7', 'Dy3O7'), ('Dy0O7', 'Dy4O6'), ('Dy1O6', 'Dy3O7'), ('Dy1O6', 'Dy5O6'), ('Dy2O6', 'Dy4O6'), ('Dy3O7', 'Dy4O6'), ('Dy3O7', 'Dy5O6')])

nx.nodes(FG)

Out[61]: NodeView(('Dy0O7', 'Dy1O6', 'Dy2O6', 'Dy3O7', 'Dy4O6', 'Dy5O6'))
```

Also I can have adjancy view, which gives the information about connected nodes with corresponding weights.

```
FG.adj

Out[64]: AdjacencyView({'Dy0O7': {'Dy1O6': {'weight': 3.0}, 'Dy2O6': {'weight': 1.0}, 'Dy3O7': {'weight': 2.0}, 'Dy4O6': {'weight': 1.0}}, 'Dy1O6': {'Dy0O7': {'weight': 3.0}, 'Dy3O7': {'weight': 1.0}, 'Dy5O6': {'weight': 1.0}}, 'Dy2O6': {'Dy0O7': {'weight': 1.0}, 'Dy4O6': {'weight': 1.0}}, 'Dy3O7': {'Dy0O7': {'weight': 2.0}, 'Dy1O6': {'weight': 1.0}, 'Dy4O6': {'weight': 3.0}, 'Dy5O6': {'weight': 1.0}}, 'Dy4O6': {'Dy0O7': {'weight': 1.0}, 'Dy2O6': {'weight': 1.0}, 'Dy3O7': {'weight': 3.0}}, 'Dy5O6': {'Dy1O6': {'weight': 1.0}, 'Dy3O7': {'weight': 1.0}}})
```

I want to use such graph properties as an input in Machine learning algorithm such as NN, How can we do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of algorithms out there to convert Graph into feature vectors. Two famous examples are:

- [Node2vec](https://snap.stanford.edu/node2vec/) from Stanford
- [Deepwalk](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.6652) from Univ. Sherbrooke

Their implementation exists on GitHub.

The underlying idea between these methods are almost the same: 1) Random walk 2) generate some sequences 3) word2vec (skip-gram) or other DL methods 4) use output as a feature vector in other Task.

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest my pip-installable library, node2vec - https://github.com/eliorc/node2vec

Comment: @bluesummers that's great, I'm not aware of that. \o/

Comment: HI Amir thank you so much for your references, through this. It seems they do the walk in a single graph with huge number of edges and nodes, but in my case I have many graphs with few number of nodes and edges.

Comment: I am accepting the answer because it helped me to go in right direction. Those links Amir provided are very useful. Thanks, Amir.